# Trying to Understand HBase

Tags: hadoop, nosql, mapreduce, hbase

The following are my questions:

1. Does Hbase use Map/Reduce in its internal work to extract data from Hadoop?
2. Can HBase be used with other frameworks such as Amazon dynamo or it has to have Hadoop as it base framework?
3. Is Hbase easy to learn?
4. What is the best way to setup an HBase instance that I can practice
   on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. HBase does not use map/reduce when you try to access a cell or row within it. Basically Hadoop stores data so that it know where a key is found (keys are stored in lexicographic order). You can see details in [this post](http://www.larsgeorge.com/2009/10/hbase-architecture-101-storage.html) by Lars George.
   HBase does support map/reduce so you can use it as a source or destination in jobs you create.
2. HBase needs Hadoop API as framework however companies like mapr or datastax provide alternate implementation of the underlying hadoop framework so technically you can also do that if you really want to
3. relative to what? :) to use a cliche I'd say that HBase is easy to learn but hard to master. You can be very quick in getting data in and out of HBase but it takes time to learn to properly design a schema, understand your usage patterns and the impacts it has on using/disabling the write-ahead-log, compactions, splits, running multiple region servers on each node or not etc.
4. the easiest would probably be to download a VM which already has hadoop installed. e.g. [these](https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/SUPPORT/CDH+Downloads) offered by Cloudera

Comment: Thank you Arnon.  I think Cloudera VM is exactly what I need in order to start to learn to work with HBase.